# how do I use jquery to clear the input in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, formtastic

Here is the haml for my form:

```
 34 #new_comment
 35   %strong Add Comment:
 36   - semantic_form_for 'comment', :url => add_comment_url(@review), :remote => true do |f|
 37     
 38     = f.text_area :comment, :label => :comment, :cols => 60,:rows => 5, :input_html => {:rows => 5, :cols => 30}
 39     = f.submit
```

After I submit, I have jquery javascript in a .js.erb file, but I can't get it to clear.  this is what I have:

```
  7 /* Reset the comment form */
  8 $("#comment_comment").reset();
```

It isn't doing anthing?

Comment: Why not just document.getElementById("comment_comment").value = ""; or .innerHTML = ""; for a textarea?

Comment: Well it was just a suggestion, it is what you would do with normal javascript if you don't use jquery ( bloatware ). document.getElementById("comment_comment") gives you the elemment, then using .value you can empty text fields in a form

Comment: how can I do it with jquery since I am using it already....

Comment: $("#comment_comment").val(""); but using normal javascript would be better in my opinion, but thats just me, and thats why its just a comment ^^

Comment: In regards to the reset not working.  The reset button will reset the value back to whatever the value was when the page loaded.  If the form has been submitted then the reset will just set it back to the value when the form loaded.  For example, if you load the page fresh and type something in the field then click the reset it will clear to blank.  If you submit a form with a value of "test" in the input, change it to "test2" then click reset it sets it back to "test".  Which makes sense because it only knows the value of input from what it was when the form was loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reset that one text area:

```
$('#comment_comment').val('');
```

Comment: What blog? It may be a jQuery plugin they were using?

Comment: My field will populate with values in the DB if I set val to "", but it can be set to " " (empty space). Why is that and how could I solve it?